# NodeJS stuck at cryto.pbkdf2Sync function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, cryptojs

So I am generating a password hash using a random salt string and a password string in a MEAN Stack application. The program successfully generates the random salt and prints it out on the console. However, it gets stuck at the pbkdf2Sync function and fails to move forward.

This is my code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
  console.log('start');
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  console.log(this.salt);
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer.alloc(password),  new Buffer.alloc(this.salt), 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
  console.log(this.hash);
};
```

The output results in:

```
start
ac09ae82b1fbb5b01257b5fa72bfc8614
```

And then the program just gets stuck here.

As far as I know, the function is not deprecated. How should I proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const hash = (password) => {
  console.log('start');
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  console.log(salt);
  const hash = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(
      new Buffer.alloc(password.length),
      new Buffer.alloc(salt.length),
      1000,
      64,
      'sha512'
    )
    .toString('hex');
  console.log(hash);
};

hash('hello world');
```

This worked for me, essentially `alloc` is looking for the number of bytes (size to allocate in memory), a string wouldn't work here.

If you're looking to use `password` and `salt` as filled Buffers (with values), then use the second argument (`fill`), in the case of password: `new Buffer.alloc(password.length, password)`.

Instead, using the `.length` to return the amount of bytes (size of string), this generated the "correct" output:

```sh
start
55387a56bd8ff87ac05be698d938ef04
ab3d65e9e6341a924c752a77b8dc6b78f1e6db5d31df7dd0cc534039dd9662a97bcaf0b959fe78248a49859c7952ddb25d66840f052b27ef1ab60b9446c0c9fd
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding

Comment: Amazing stuff! On second review, use the fill argument or else the encryption won't be using your actual values, an overlook on my side, all the best.